# How to remove cycles in a graph by *unfolding* them using `graph-tool`?

Tags: python, nodes, directed-acyclic-graphs, graph-tool, digraphs

Using `graph-tool`, I want to remove cycles in a graph by *unfolding* them. That is, if there is a cycle, pick a node as *root* and make a copy of it such that the last edge in the path from *root* to *root* now has the copy as target. Something like the example below, where the node copy is highlighted with a green contour.

```
# define graph with cycle
g = Graph()
v1 = g.add_vertex()
v2 = g.add_vertex()
v3 = g.add_vertex()
e1 = g.add_edge(v1, v2)
e2 = g.add_edge(v2, v3)
e3 = g.add_edge(v3, v1)
g.vp["foo"] =g.new_vp("int",[1,2,3])
g.ep["bar"] =g.new_ep("string",["a","e","i"])
```

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| A cycle with *root*=1 | A cycle, unfolded |

To solve this, I wrote the function below.

```
def cyunfold(g,cycle,vps=None,eps=None):
  # get edge to "unfold"
  last=ifelse(len(cycle)==1,cycle[0],cycle[-1])
  first=cycle[0]
  # create new vertex
  newv=g.add_vertex()
  # copy vertex properties
  for v in vps:
      prop=g.vp[v]
      prop[newv]=prop[first]
  olde=g.edge(last,first)
  # create new edges
  newe=g.add_edge(g.vertex(last),g.vertex(newv))
  # copy edge properties
  for e in eps:
      prope=g.ep[e]
      prope[newe]=prope[olde]
  # remove old edge
  g.remove_edge(olde)
  # add copy indicator as vertex property
  if g.vp.get("iscopy")==None:
    g.vp["iscopy"]=g.new_vp("bool")
  iscopy=g.vp["iscopy"]
  iscopy[newv]=True
  return(iscopy)
```

Which, when applied to this example, works:

```
iscopy=cyunfold(g,cypath,['foo'],['bar'])
```

However, I'm not sure this solution is scalable.
Is there a graph-tool function, something like `gt`'s `infect_vertex_property` that could help me achieve this efficiently? Or maybe using loopless iteration?